# Подключение RTX64 библиотек к Builder 10.3

Tags: c++builder

Надо подключить RTX64 от IntervalZero к Builder 10, чтобы возможно было использовать команды по созданию таймера прямиком в билдере. Знаю что можно через 2 проги от visual studio и 1 builder работать с rtx, но мне надо именно напрямую на builder. Я взял нужные h файлы, и достал rtapi.dll, который впоследствии конвертировал с помощью implib в lib и их подключил к проекту , но все равно при обращении к командам например RtCreateTimer, выдает  unresolved function.